# How can I call dispatch from within a createAsynchThunk using typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I created a new react redux toolkit app, and just having an issue trying to call dispatch from inside of a createAsyncThunk call.

```
export const fetchBoardAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  'board/fetchBoard',
  async (boardId: string, thunkApi: { dispatch: (arg0: { type: string; response: { data: any; }; "": any; }) => void; } ) => {
    const response = await fetchBoard();
    console.log('fetch board returned data...' + JSON.stringify(response.data.board));
    //thunkApi.dispatch({ type: 'board/setBoard', payload: response.data })
    return response.data;
  }
);

export const boardSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'board',
  initialState,
  // The `reducers` field lets us define reducers and generate associated actions
  reducers: {
      setBoard: (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
          state.board = action.payload;
      }
  },
  // The `extraReducers` field lets the slice handle actions defined elsewhere,
  // including actions generated by createAsyncThunk or in other slices.
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchBoardAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.board += action.payload.data;
      });
  },
});
```

So I currently have the call commented out:

```
 //thunkApi.dispatch({ type: 'board/setBoard', payload: response.data })
```

When I uncomment it, I get this type error:

```
Argument of type '{ type: string; payload: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ type: string; response: { data: any; }; "": any; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'payload' does not exist in type '{ type: string; response: { data: any; }; "": any; }'.ts(2345)
```

Is the type on the thunkApi parameter correct also?

```
async (boardId: string, thunkApi: { dispatch: (arg0: { type: string; response: { data: any; }; "": any; }) => void; } ) => {
```

I need help trying to call this dispatch so I can save the payload response to my redux store using this method...

Answer (score 0):

`createAsyncThunk` already abstracts the step to dispatch inside of it when everything goes ok, with redux toolkit all you have to fulfill a thunk is to return a value, said value will be passed in the action object to the thunk.fulfilled. Meaning you would not need to dispatch to the `setBoard` reducer, the `fetchBoardAsync.fulfilled` extra reducer will receive the return of your `createAsyncThunk`.
`thunkApi` is used in other cases where you need to cancel the request or reject it with an error.

Comment: what if I wanted to dispatch an action to update another slice somewhere else?

Comment: you can use the dispatch method inside the thunkAPI object, I would suggest that you let typescript infer the types for your functions otherwise supply it with the necessary generics 
`createAsyncThunk<returnType,paramType,{state?: unknown; dispatch?: Dispatch; extra?: unknown; rejectValue?: unknown; serializedErrorType?: unknown; pendingMeta?: unknown; fulfilledMeta?: unknown; rejectedMeta?: unknown;}>`